# split qualified class in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, split

We will get 'Person' as the output by executing below query in Oracle.

```
select SUBSTR ('com.test.Person', INSTR ('com.test.Person', '.', -1) + 1) 
from dual;
```

What can be the right alternative query in postgresql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `regexp_math()` which returns an array of matches:

```
with data (col) as (
  values 
    ('com.test.Person'), 
    ('com.test.fruit.Apple'), 
    ('com.test.color.Red')
)
select (regexp_match(col, '\w+$'))[1] result
from data;
```

Alternatively you could convert the string into an array and take the last element:

```
with data (col) as (
  values 
    ('com.test.Person'), 
    ('com.test.fruit.Apple'), 
    ('com.test.color.Red')
)
select (string_to_array(col, '.'))[cardinality(string_to_array(col, '.'))]
from data;
```